# CS0672: Member `Foo.OnSelected()' overrides obsolete member `Baz.OnSelected()'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

In my DLL I have marked a virtual method as obsolete using `System.ObsoleteAttribute` but this is not producing the warning which I had expected.

**DLL Source (Baz):**

```
[Obsolete("This method has become obsolete, please override `OnEnable` instead.")]
public virtual void OnSelected() {
}

public virtual void OnEnable() {
}
```

**User Source (Foo):**

```
// CS0672 - Doesn't show useful message...
public override void OnSelected() {
}
```

The following warning is logged upon building the project:

> CS0672: Member `Foo.OnSelected()` overrides obsolete member `Baz.OnSelected()`.
>   Add the Obsolete attribute to `Foo.OnSelected()'

But I would like my custom obsolete message to appear dominant in this warning so that my customers can follow the provided instructions. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please show your work..

Comment: Will your customers use the source or a compiled assembly?

Comment: @Trajan Customers reference the compiled assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second parameter to your attribute constructor to tell the compiler to throw a compilation error (rather than the usual "method is obsolete" warning) and the error will use your attribute's message. **The error will only occur if the method is called.**

```
[Obsolete("This method has become obsolete, please override `OnEnable` instead.", true)]
public virtual void OnSelected() {
}
```

Note that this will not remove the CS0672 warning.